# Performance issues in javascript onclick handler

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, user-interface, cross-browser

I have written a game in java script and while it works, it is slow responding to multiple clicks.  Below is a very simplified version of the code that I am using to handle clicks and it is still fails to respond to a second click of 2 if you don't wait long enough.  Is this something that I need to just accept or is there a faster way to be ready for the next click?

BTW, I attach this function using AddEvent from the quirksmode recoding contest.

```
var selected = false;
var z = null;
function handleClicks(evt) {
    evt = (evt)?evt:((window.event)?window.event:null);
    if (selected) {
        z.innerHTML = '<div class="rowbox a">a</div>';
        selected = false;
    } else {
        z.innerHTML = '<div class="rowbox selecteda">a</div>';
        selected = true;
    }
}
```

The live code may be seen at http://www.omega-link.com/index.php?content=testgame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that the 2nd click is registering as a dblclick event, not as a click event.  The change is happening quickly, but the 2nd click is ignored unless you wait.  I would suggest changing to either the mousedown or mouseup event.

Comment: Changing to mouse up seems to have done the trick.  Thanks.  Of course, now I need to lookup how to remove the handler in a cross platform manner, but that is minor.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to only change the classname instead of removing/adding a div to the DOM (which is what the innerHTML property does).

Something like:

```
var selected = false;
var z = null;

function handleClicks(evt) 
{
    var tmp;

    if(z == null)
       return;

    evt = (evt)?evt:((window.event)?window.event:null);
    tmp = z.firstChild;
    while((tmp != null) && (tmp.tagName != 'DIV'))
        tmp = tmp.firstChild;
    if(tmp != null)
    {
      if (selected) 
      {
        tmp.className = "rowbox a";
        selected = false;
      } else 
      {
        tmp.className = "rowbox selecteda";
        selected = true;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: While it doesn't address the problem that I was having, you do make an excellent point about not deleting and recreating if I don't have to.  +1

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is the changing of the `innerHTML` which changes the DOM which is a huge performance problem.

Comment: Ok, I've actually tried this with both innerHTML and DOM methods. Both seem to respond at the same speed.  First click responds with out a bit of delay (the block gets highlighed) and the second click works great if it doesn't occur too soon after the first (I'm guessing at the timming here, but around 1/4 second)
In the normal game a user would click on a block to highlight it, then click again to remove the block.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you may want to compare the performance of innerHTML against document.createElement()  or even:

```
el.style.display = 'block' // turn off display: none.
```

Profiling your code may be helpful as you A/B various refactorings:

- http://www.mozilla.org/performance/jsprofiler.html
- http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/profiler/
- http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2009/03/26/ie-8-can-profile-javascript.aspx

Comment: In general a good idea, so the +1.  However, I had tried both ways and there was little if any difference.